# CAPTCHA fails every time on some forms (captcha session reuse attack detected)

Tags: 7, version-control

I'm using/running the [Captcha module 7.x-1.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha/releases/7.x-1.x-dev) the latest version for D7 but on some forms I am still getting **captcha session reuse attack detected**

I have tried 9 patches and it is STILL not working.

i don't know what else to do.

Comment: is that the latest stable release? why are you using dev release

Comment: @ReesGargi  Because the so called stable release was giving me that problem in the first place, and after the 9 patches did not work I decided to go for that dev release in the thinking it would have the latest patched code for my issue.

Comment: @ReesGargi and a lot of patches and problems recorded on this issue are quite old as well.

Comment: I tried the stable release on sandbox, it is working. what types of forms are you talking about?

Comment: @ReesGargi   webforms

Comment: You should do a bug report regarding this on the project's page. In the meantime, you could try using [ReCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) OR [Draggable Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggable_captcha)